# Action method being called multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

I've just spotted something quite strange about an action method that is being called, via a simple click of a link, in my MVC 3 site.  For some reason this action method is being called multiple times.  Not only that but subsequent calls get called before previous ones complete.  What I mean is, suppose I have 10 lines of code in my action method, numbered 1, 2 ... 10.  The first call of the method will execute lines 1,2 and 3.  The second call executes lines 1,2,3 and 4, then the third call executes lines 1,2,3 and 4 and then the first continues from line 4 and so on.  It's as if multiple threads are calling this action method, but as far as I can see nothing of the sort is happening because all I do to get this to happen is click on a link.  Is there any reason why this should happen?

**UPDATE**

Actually, having done analysis, I can see that it is 2 calls that are being made.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy.  Have you actually seen each separate call in Fiddler?

Comment: That sounds very strange indeed. Can you post the code?

Comment: What is the "link" that you're clicking?  Is there a submit occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, here was the culprit

```
<div class="listing-holder" onclick="window.location='/Lot/Details/@auction.Id'">
   <a href="/Lot/Details/@auction.Id"><img src="@auctionLineModel.ImageUrl" alt="auction Image"/></a>
   ...
</div>
```

As you can see there is an onclick on the div and a href.  Both were being called.  Doh!